# Differences in Elasticsearch' Types of Fields

Tags: elasticsearch

So there are source fields, document fields and stored fields. But what's the difference in them? I read [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/modules-scripting.html#_document_fields) about it, but they are still all the same to me. And then there are also [script fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/search-request-script-fields.html).

Maybe as a starting point:

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my-index/my-type/1' -d '{
    "@timestamp": "2015-07-22T09:00:00.000Z",
    "user": "sjngm",
    "message": "It's kinda warm in here",
    "happiness": 89
}'
```

and this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['happiness'].value > 50" }}}}}
```

compared to

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "_source['happiness'] > 50" }}}}}
```

This throws a NullPointerException:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "_fields['happiness'].value > 50" }}}}}
```

What do those types stand for? Where do they come from? When do I use what?

And maybe a bonus question: Is it possible to generate additional fields into "hits/hits/_source" in the response with any of the above? Maybe with a variation of script fields?

Can anyone please provide an explanation in simple English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `doc["my-field"].value` provides `*.raw`, loads all the values in fielddata completely independent of filters => fast, uses lots of RAM
- `_source["my-field"]` loads the document as compressed JSON from disk and parses it for the field => may take some time, parsing is done by streaming => later fields take longer to be found
- `_fields["my-field"].value` accesses only special fields marked in the index' mappings as `"store": true`